# External ID in OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

I'm doing a customization of the `purchase` app from openerp, i need to define some external ID's in the system.

Where should i define them?

I thought it will be in the `base` module, but no luck, if i define a new group there it throws me the same `ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system` , so i'm stuck on it, can't find a clear or step by step explanation...

Anybody know how can i define these external ID's, whatever they are or do, into OpenErp?

Should be in PostgreSQL? If so, where exactly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm creating a pseudo-custom module, from purchase app, so i changed for example the res.users groups names, for example base.group_user to base.group_usuario, so obviously the latter is not defined as an external ID in the system, how can i define it? By editing 'base' module?

Comment: Nevermind i solved this by adding the external ID's on .csv in the Settings section of the web-server.